# Stream html file to PhantomJS from Java

Tags: java, phantomjs

Right now I'm using PhantomJS to read a local html file(which only contains an svg image) and output it as a png. It works great.

But I'm trying to accomplish the following and I'm not sure if its possible or if my solution is perhaps way off. I want to perform the same task as mentioned above but the svg will be different each time. So using a java servlet, my plan was to call phantomjs from the servlet and pass it the new html/svg code so it could generate the png.

Now, I know I could simply create the html chart on the file system & run phantomJS, but that would would require slow disk I/O writing & Java would need to wait for the file to be completed before I could run phantomJS. I was hoping I could eliminate the slow I/O writing step and simply "stream" my html/svg file to PhantomJS when I call it from my java servlet.

Is this possible? If so, any tips on how it can be accomplished. Or if I'm way off, is there another better way? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any update? I am trying to reach a similar implementation

Comment: @AntonioAcevedo

I had completely forgot I had asked this question. Unfortunately, streaming does not appear to be an option. I looked into using an SSD to speed up the I/O interaction. I also looked into using phantomjscloud.com, to avoid some overhead on my own server. At the end, I scrapped the whole project as the solutions were not good enough for my project. If you find a better solution, please don't forget to share it with the community.